# How to use sed to remove ./ between two characters in Unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I am trying to remove `./` between two characters using `sed` but not getting the desired output.

Sample:

```
e2b66a3d84ee448c33d7f2a2f7e51c58  ./2017_06_10_0400.txt
```

I tried the below but it is not working as expected, even the `.` in the "`.txt`" is getting removed.

```
sed -i 's/[./,]//g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware: don't even think of using the `-i` option until you know the code is working.  You can screw things up big time!

Use:

```
sed -e 's%[.]/%%g'
```

You can choose the delimiter in a `s///` command, and when the regular expressions involve `/`, it is sensible to choose something else — I often use `%` when it doesn't figure in the text.  The `-e` is optional.  Using `[.]` to detect an actual dot is one way; you can write `\.` if you prefer, but I'm allergic to avoidable backslashes (if you've never had to write 16 backslashes in a row to get `troff` to do what you want, you haven't suffered enough).

Be aware that the `-i` option behaves differently in GNU `sed` and BSD (macOS) `sed`.  Using `-i.bak` works in both (for an arbitrary, non-empty string such as `.bak`).  Otherwise, your code isn't portable (which may or may not matter to you now, but might well do later on).

You have:

```
sed -i 's/[./,]//g'
```

The trouble with this is that it looks for any of the characters `.`, `/` or `,` in isolation — so it removes the `.` in `.txt` as well as the `.` and `/` in `./`.  You need to look for consecutive characters — as in my suggested solution.

Comment: thanks for explaining it so clearly. This works great, am still new to shell and finding my way. This definitely helps. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
echo "e2b66a3d84ee448c33d7f2a2f7e51c58  ./2017_06_10_0400.txt" | sed -e 's|\./||'
```

Comment: That will remove `x/` as well as `./` because `.` is the 'any one character' wild-card in regular expressions (as opposed to shell globbing).  With the example data, it works, but it is rather dangerous in general — it does more than it is supposed to do.

Comment: Yea, this did work as expected. But thanks for pointing that out @JonathanLeffler

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Escape the period. This should match the period itself.

Comment: That works — it avoids over-enthusiastic removal of data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use escape character `\`

```
's#\.\/##g'
```

```
:=>echo "e2b66a3d84ee448c33d7f2a2f7e51c58  ./2017_06_10_0400.txt"  | sed 's#\.\/##g' 
e2b66a3d84ee448c33d7f2a2f7e51c58  2017_06_10_0400.txt
:=>
```